# Batch command to create empty txt files with the file names in a folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder of files, e.g:
001zzzqqq.*
002bbbccc.*
003nnnfff.*
...

And want to create a blank text file named after each of those files, e.g:
001zzzqqq.txt
002bbbccc.txt
003nnnfff.txt
...

Any quick way to knock this up in batch file? My mind seems to have gone blank on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Iterate over the files in the folder:

```
for %x in (*) do ...
```

Create empty files:

```
type NUL > %~nx.txt
```

The `%~nx` evaluates to the file name without the extension of the loop variable `%x`. So, combined:

```
for %x in (*) do type NUL > %~nx.txt
```

You could also use `copy NUL %~nx.txt` but that will output `1 file(s) copied` and throw errors if the text file already exists; this is the more silent variant (or use `copy /Y NUL %~nx.txt >NUL 2>&1`).

In a batch file you need to double the `%` but you won't need a batch file just for this one-liner (except it's part of a larger program):

```
for %%x in (*) do type NUL > %%~nx.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('dir /B') do (
  wuauclt > %%~na.txt
)
```

Comment: `for` can iterate over files just fine, you don't need to drag `dir` and tokenizing into this. Your code breaks with Unicode file names when the console is set to raster fonts as well as with file names that contain spaces (two reasons not to use `for /f` in such cases). Also using a random program to output nothing is ... questionable, at least from the point of someone having to read this.